# Creating ZPL template for Zebra Printer ZP450ctp

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

This is the first time I've worked with ZPL code. I'm printing on a 200dpi ZP450ctp printer onto labels that are 2inx1in. The .zpl below is way to big but I thought I had it set right. Is anyone familiar with the .zpl language?

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW1200
^LL0600
^LS0
^FT131,350^A0N,333,331^FH\^FDA12345^FS
^BY4,3,70^FT717,533^BCN,,Y,N
^FD>:A>51234>65^FS
^FT138,539^A0N,58,57^FH\^FDThis is a description^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your print width would then be 400 and label length would be 100. If you are using web based media you do not need to have these in your ZPL (remove the ^PW and ^LL).

Then you need to set the values right. Character height and with in your ^A0 command would make each character 1.5 inches.

```
^XA
^MMT
^FO10,10^A0N,80,80^FH\^FDA12345^FS
^BY4,3,50^FO10,130^BCN,,Y,N
^FD>:A>51234>65^FS
^FO10,95^A0N,30,30^FH\^FDThis is a description^FS
^XZ
```

Try the above it should get you closer to what you need. You want to adjust the ^FO commands to adjust the location of the objects, and adjust the pair of numbers after the ^AON, to adjust the font size.